# Image Assets catalog doesnt recognise retina 4 photos in xCode5

Tags: ios, xcode, image, assets, catalog

For start what I am trying to do i am not even sure that is possible(looks that is)
In the feature of image assets in Xcode you can select for an imageSet to be either Universal or Device Specific. When I am doing it Device Specific and select both iphone and Retina 4 and assign pics to all , it is always selected the iphone retina image and never the Retina 4 when I am using an iphone 5(device or simulator)

Have searched docs but couldnt find something.
Thanks

Comment: I too am having the same issue. I thought it would work but maybe not..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The "R4" image will only work on 4-inch iPhone running iOS 7 or later. 
On older version of iOS it will use 2x image.

Example. If you use images like this:

[image: Xcode 5 screenshot]

you will see:

- iPhone 5 iOS >= 7 - number 3,
- iPhone 5 iOS < 7 - number 2,
- iPhone 4, 4S - number 2,
- iPhone 3GS - number 1,
- iPhone 5C and 5S - number 3.

Comment: In my experience, this does not work as you have described UNLESS the project's Deployment Target specifies specifically iOS 7.0.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, this is the case whenever you do not target specifically iOS 7.0 in your Deployment Target as part of your Project/Workspace settings.

[image: iOS 6.1 targeted - needs iOS 7.0!]

Targeting anything other than 7.0 seems to result in this behavior.

To clarify: this value essentially specifies the minimum version of iOS that is allowed to run your app. Specifying iOS 7.0 in this field will restrict use of your app/update to ONLY users with iOS 7.0.

Comment: If Deployment Target == iOS 7, items in asset catalogs are compiled into a unified, efficient runtime format (=Assets.car). If Deployment Target < iOS 7 the images are exported to their expected format (e.g ~ipad, ~ipad@2x, etc). Unfortunately in this scenario iphone5-images are not recognized.

Comment: How to fix this issue in iOS6

Comment: @Thangavel, as I understand it, if you're targeting iOS < 7 you can still use R4-sized images, but don't use Asset Catalogs.  If you're targeting only iOS 7+, go ahead and use Asset Catalogs and you'll get your R4 images.