# iOS - App Displaying Scrunched Pre-Retina Version

Tags: ios, retina-display

I have an iOS app that was working fine. Displaying fine, operating fine. When I uninstalled it and gave it a fresh install, about an half an inch on both the top and bottom of the screen is black. It appears to be thinking it's an older iPhone and trying to fit it into a smaller screen. I don't recall changing anything related to this. Any ideas what it might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing this in iPhone5 (4 inch size device) than you are finding box layout (black margin top bottom ) hope i am assuming right than

please check your **splash image from iPhone5 that is 640x1136** it is not load right now or it would be missing in your application.

add splash screen for 4 size device it will work.

If you are using image-assets for splash screen than add this image in R4

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? I'm not sure how to do anything that you've said.

Comment: I am saying about Launch image do you check you set launch image with size 640x1136 for 4.7 size device

Comment: I added a splash image for both 4 inch settings. I don't see anything for 4.7. No changes. I am using image-assets, btw.

Comment: Okay, that fixed it. For the most part. Now there's a weird splash screen that's a bit stretched.

Comment: sorry for 4 inch device 4.7 is my mistake for 4 inch you need set image in image asset R4

Comment: your application support 6.0 than image of R4 not support in image assets please check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744554/image-assets-catalog-doesnt-recognise-retina-4-photos-in-xcode5 may this stretched your image

Comment: Technically I'm seeing two images. One is just fine, and another one is nearly identical but stretched behind it.

Comment: You need to add 3 images 1 is size 320x480 that is normal image 2nd is retina images @2x that is 640x960 and third one is 640x1136 last one set in R4 image you may give 3 image name as Default-568.png

Comment: It seems that the icon that rests on the phone's menu is expanding\stretching as a background behind the 640X1136 one. Does this mean I have to add more variety of images like you say earlier?

Comment: for image that used for whole screen for that you need to image with above mention size for icon refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph/18737063#18737063

Comment: Here's the problem: it's a square image that's being stretched to fit into a rectangle. I made it 120x120, but it's still stretching. Why is the icon moving into the background?