# Xcode 6 how to set separate @2x images for iPhone 5 and 6 devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I want to specify different background images for iPhone each device. Like this

```
iPhone 6 Plus   1242x2208 pixels    bg@3x.png
iPhone 6        750x1334  pixels    bg@2x.png
iPhone 5        640x1136  pixels    bg@2x.png
iPhone 4        640x960   pixels    bg@2x.png
iPhone 3GS      320x480   pixels    bg.png
```

In `LaunchImage` there is option available to specify images for `Retina HD 4.7` device. So no problem for Launch Images.

[image]

In `.xcassets` file, I have option for `1x`, `2x`, `Retina 4 2x` and `3x`. But there is no option for `iPhone 6 (1334x750)` device.

[image]

So how to provide `1334x750 px` image for iPhone 6 device? Looking for some solution using `.xcassets` file, not by programmatically loading images for each device.

I have already visited the related SO's questions, but none of them answers specifically for iPhone 6 device images.

[iPhone 6 Plus resolution confusion: Xcode or Apple's website? for development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25755443/1444321)

[xcode 6 asset catalog iphone 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26604477/1444321)

Comment: Retina 4.7 same with Retina 4 @2x. iPhone 6 is 326 ppi, plus is 401 ppi.

Comment: @ValarMorghulis, they have even different point sizes, only aspect ratio is same. not?

Comment: Yes, u right. iPhone 6 is 667x375 points and iPhone 5 is 568x320 points. But works with same scale @2x, I don't know why :)

Comment: So I should provide all images with 667x375, and skip for 568x320 completely?

Comment: And what If I want to display different images based on iPhone 5 and 6 devices?

Comment: skip 667x375, provide all images with 568x320(1136 x 640 resolution).

Comment: So 568x320 (a smaller resolution) would be re-sampled to 667x375 (a bigger resolution). Wouldn't it add distortion in images?

Comment: Apple itself does upsampling and downsampling of images for iphone 6 and iphone 6+ in iOS8, so just have to provide 640x1136@2x and 1242x2208@3x. We donot need to provide images for iphone 6 as 750x1334@2x. isn't it?

Comment: @AadilAli, what if my design requires different images for iPhone 5 and 6?

Answer (score 1):

set your image name like this;

> image-320@2x//iPhone 5
>
> image-375@2x//iPhone 6

```
NSNumber *screenWidth = @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%@", screenWidth];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But as I already described in question, I was looking for some solution that doesn't require programming.

Comment: And if there isn't such an answer (and I don't believe there is), here's your answer.

Comment: Thanks mate! No more ifs, I would also use heights to differentiate between 4s and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Images.xcassets has option to provide separate image for iPhone 5(Retina 4 @2x), iPhone 6(@2x) and iPhone 6 plus(3x).

[image]

There is no option for iPhone 4 asset(probably apple is stopping iPhone 4 support) rather it takes @2x images (scale mode) for iPhone 4 also but you can do something like [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26604477/xcode-6-asset-catalog-iphone-6#answer-28457343) for iPhone 4

Update Xcode 7

There is no option for separate image with Images.xcassets now in Xcode 7, We have to use same 2x images for all Retina devices and 3x for Retina HD device

Comment: You haven't answer the question. OP have done it and he provided your link already.

Comment: I think the 2x icon is mean to be used in iPhone 4/4S instead of iPhone 6?

Comment: 2x images are for all retina devices, Although they given option for iPhone 5 separately in Xcode 6 but removed in Xcode 7

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly do different stuff on different devices, you need to do it in  code for now, like [Valar Morghulis said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26860257/4674348).

```
NSNumber *screenWidth = @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image-%@", screenWidth];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

OR, you can use UIDevice class to get that information. It has several methods with boolean returns you can use to get various information about the device:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] platform]
[[UIDevice currentDevice] hasRetinaDisplay]
[[UIDevice currentDevice] hasMultitasking]
```

OR, you can include `<sys/sysctl.h>` and;

```
NSString *platform = [self platform];

if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])    return @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
```

so on and so forth. You can learn about device strings at [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models).

There are some other ways to do this programmatically, But as of now, there is no explicit way to do this in the interface builder that I know of. Feel free to point out my mistakes.